# 3rd party metadata links from ACRCloud

Tags: acrcloud

When i get 'external_metadata' how can I make Spotify and iTunes links on [ACRCloud metadata](https://www.acrcloud.com/docs/metadata/music/). How can I make a working link?

```
                "spotify": {
                    "track": {
                        "id": "1H8XgJUdCuG22jSVTi6nkL"
                    }
                },
                "itunes": {
                    "track": {
                        "id": 529354556
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spotify: You can refer to Spotify Developers (https://developer.spotify.com/) to make up the URL. So you need to put the track id at the end of this URL: https://open.spotify.com/track/{id}  e.g. https://open.spotify.com/track/1H8XgJUdCuG22jSVTi6nkL

For iTunes, You can refer to iTunes Affiliate Resource (https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/apple-music-best-practices-for-app-developers/) to make up the URL.

Comment: Hi there @W I wasn't able to figure out the iTunes one, may you please guide me some more on that.